# How the partial dependence was calculated in sklearn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

When the dependent variable is binary, I understand the Y-axis is the logit(Y),
but when the dependent variable is continuous, I found that the Y-axis is still taking negtive value ( there are no negtive values in trainging sample, and the min(pred_y)>0), like the chart.

[image]

SO I'm confused that What is the Y?

I want to know that for each point in the grid , How exactly the Y is calcualted, such as what are the values of other Xs?

BTW, after I trained a GradientBoostingRegressor, How can I output all the tree to a txt file , such as all the predictors, threholds and node value

Comment: You need to give a lot more background information about what you're doing. `scikit-learn` is a large package, and we're not mind readers. :-)

Comment: I was using the 'GradientBoostingRegressor' to predict the continous variable, I just want to know when I use the 'plot_partial_dependence', what is the Y-axis stands for ? and how the each point was calcualted. Since There no detailed explanation in the manal.